# I can't get the name of my NXT

Tags: c#, nxt

I'm working on a project with an NXT and using c#, and I wanted to make sure I could connect my NXT with a test console program first. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using NKH.MindSqualls;

namespace NxtTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NxtBrick brick = new NxtBrick(NxtCommLinkType.USB, 0);
            NxtUsbConnection conn = new NxtUsbConnection();

            conn.Connect();

            NxtGetDeviceInfoReply? reply = conn.GetDeviceInfo();
            if (reply.HasValue)
                Console.WriteLine("Nxt name: {0}", reply.Value.nxtName);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Nope");

            conn.Disconnect();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

My console keep telling me "Nope".
My code is inspired from http://www.mindsqualls.net/QuickStart_2_0.aspx

Comment: The code to rename the NXT seems to be included in the website. Test if you can rename the NXT, then read the new name back.

Comment: It didn't change anything, but thanks for the idea. (I think the NXT has a default name if none is given.)

Comment: In testing, you do not make such assumptions.

Comment: I don't make assumptions, I just refer to my tutorial.
www.mindsqualls.net/QuickStart_2_0.aspx